# How to prompt for function use be used within a function?

Tags: functions, interactive, prompt

Consider the following example function

```
(defun simple-function ()
  (dotimes (counter 10)
           (input-function)))
```

This requires `input-function` to be hard coded within the definition of `simple-function`. How can I have `simple-function` prompt the user for the function that they would want to use in place of `input-function`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to use an interactive code to prompt you for the function.

```
(defun  simple-function (input-function)
  (interactive "aInput function: ")
  (dotimes (counter 10)
    (funcall input-function)))
```

then you can write your own input like this perhaps, even using the counter variable from your loop.

```
(defun myfunc ()
  (message "%s: %s" counter
       (read-string "string: ")))
```

To use these, type `M-x simple-function` then you should be prompted for a function name. type `myfunc`, and press Enter (`RET`), and it should prompt you 10 times for a string.